# I can fetch my entities that I save only on the first launch. If I relaunch the app, I can't fetch my entities

Tags: objective-c, core-data, afnetworking, objective-c-blocks, nsmanagedobject

I have a weird behavior.
When the app is launched for the first time, I execute multiple `GET` request to download some data.

I download my data with `AFURLConnectionOperation batchOfRequestOperations` :

**Here is the code for multiple `GET` requests:**

```
-(void)refreshData:(NSMutableArray *)mutableOperations
{
    NSArray *operations = [AFURLConnectionOperation batchOfRequestOperations:mutableOperations progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {
        NSLog(@"%lu of %lu complete", numberOfFinishedOperations, totalNumberOfOperations);
    } completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
        [self.delegate dataRefreshingDone];
    }];
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperations:operations waitUntilFinished:NO];
}
```

In mutableOperation, I have an operation to download some `Directors`, and when I receive my directors, I save them in my CoreData :

**Code for the operation of `GET` directors :**

```
 - (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)getOperationGetDirectors
    {
        NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/api/diretors", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:kBaseURL]]];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
        operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
        [operation.responseSerializer setAcceptableContentTypes:[operation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"]];

        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            if ([[responseObject objectForKey:@"success"] intValue] == 1) {

                // I GET THE MANAGED
                AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
                NSManagedObjectContext* context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

                NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
                [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Director"
                                                    inManagedObjectContext:context]];

                NSMutableArray *directorsArray= [responseObject objectForKey:@"data"];
                for (NSMutableDictionary *directorReceived in directorsArray) {
                    // Do lots of things with the context.
                    Director *director = (Director *)[NSEntityDescription
                                                      insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Director"
                                                      inManagedObjectContext:context];
                    NSArray *availableKeys = [[director.entity attributesByName] allKeys];
                    if ([propertyName isEqualToString:@"mostFamousMovie"]) {
                      // This case is a relationship. A director has a most famous movie. 
                      // So we get the most famous movie thanks to the id of the movie in the JSON
                         NSDictionary *mostFamousMovieReceived = [mostFamousMovieReceived objectForKey:propertyName];
                         Movie *movie = (Movie *)[GenericCoreData getEntityById:[mostFamousMovieReceived objectForKey:@"id"] forEntityName:@"Movie"];
                         if (movie) {
                            [director setValue:movie forKey:propertyName];
                         }
                     }                    
                    else if ([availableKeys containsObject:propertyName]) {
                        [director setValue:[directorReceived objectForKey:propertyName] forKey:propertyName];
                    }
                }
                NSError *error;
                if ([context save:&error]) {
                }
            }
        }
          failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
              // ERROR HANDLING
          }];
        return operation;
    }
```

After I saved them, and I go on my `DirectorsViewController` (I fetch all my director to display them on a tableView). It works pretty well.

**My `getEntityById`of my `GenericCoreData` class**

```
+ (NSManagedObject *)getEntityById:(id)entityId forEntityName:(NSString *)entityName
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext* context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName
                                        inManagedObjectContext:context]];
    NSError *error = nil;
    [fetchRequest setIncludesPropertyValues:YES];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@", entityId]];
    NSArray *fetchResult = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    NSManagedObject *managedObjectFound = nil;
    if (fetchResult && [fetchResult count] == 1) {
        managedObjectFound = [fetchResult objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return managedObjectFound;
}
```

**Here how I fetch my directors :**

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext* context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Director"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
[request setEntity:entity];
NSError *error = nil;
NSLog(@"FETCH Director IN DIRECTOR VIEW CONTROLLER = %@", [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]);
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (error) {
    // Handle the error.
}
// We set the array of directors array for the tableView
[self setDirectorsArray:mutableFetchResults];
```

After this... If I **recompile**, or even I just **kill the app** through the simulator. If I go back on my app. My fetch request returns me an **empty array**, or an **array with just one director**. It can't be possible because I saved very more directors, and the fetch worked very well on the first launch of the app.

After some researches... I'm wonderring if there are conflicts with the `ManagedObjectContext`... The fact that it is executed in a `successBlock` of the operation... Or maybe there is a problem with the relationships of my entities...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked my tables, and I had to edit my relationships. They were bi-directionnal. I just had to delete the relationship in other tables, and to keep the relationships only on the owner table (no inverse basically) ... Of course, in some case, you will need to keep your inverse relationship. It depends if you need it or not.

To conclude, if you have this kind of error again, just review your relationships.